# Order of if statements?

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

I wonder if the first `if` statement is True, whether are the following `elif` executed or not (even if they are also True) ?

I have tried:

```
if True:
    print "Hi"
elif True:
    print "hello"
```

And it prints only "Hi". But in a more complex part of my code, I see some print outputs displayed that are within some `elif` statements and I just basically switch the very first if to True so that none of the `elif` should be executed for testing purposes. So why are the print statement that are within the `elif` printed?

(code is too long to print here, I just wonder if it could be an answer without...)

Comment: If the `if` condition is true, the **corresponding** `elif` and `else` conditions and bodies will *not* be evaluated.

Comment: That's what I thought until I see some "print" statement that are within `elif` printed to stdout. I must check what's wrong...

Comment: If you have an example of an `elif` block executing under a `true` `if` statement, you should post it. The code you've posted is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

An `elif` will only be entered **if the condition matches *and* the previous condition does not:**

```
>>> if x == True:
...     print 'hi'
... elif x == False:
...     print 'bye'
... 
hi
>>> if x == True:
...     print 'hi'
... elif x == True:
...     print 'bye' #not entered because previous condition was valid
... 
hi
>>>
```

Comment: I suppose that's because the question makes no sense, so good answers are not really possible...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (which is unanswerable). _Why are the print statements that are within the `elif` printed?_

Comment: No @Mitch the question is "if the first if statement is True, whether are the following elif executed". This answer correctly answers that question. The OP says he has an example of it not being true, but can't seem to provide it.

Comment: @MarkM That is arguable - read the rest of their question please.

Comment: @Mitch I suppose the last sentence is also a question. But the answer is he has a flaw in his program (or there is a serious bug in python that he is the first to discover).

Comment: @MarkM Which is precisely why the question is unanswerable, and should be closed rather than provided with general statement answers for "how does an if statement work".

Comment: So, I totally agree with Jean-François Fabre, but I can't delete the question. If some administrator get there, you can delete this thread as it's pointed as useless. Sorry for the inconvenience.  I'll go to further investigations by my side and will come back with a complete structured question as well as an exhaustive code example if I find out what's going wrong on my code.

Comment: you _could_ delete it if none of the answers had positive vote count. You can always flag the question and explain that you want to delete.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but have you tried `else`?

```
if True:
  print "Hi"
else:
  print "Hello"
```

EDIT: Sorry, understood what you mean now.. 
I might be wrong, but "elif" means "else if"
So what you're basicly writing is like this:

If i have 5 apples, i put up a hand
else if i have 5 apples, i put up a leg.

using `elif` should however not be used at the end of a statement/code. If you aren't going to compare more than 2 statements, use 'if' and 'else'

But why should you have 2 'True'?

Comment: In fact, I have a bunch of 6 `elif` before the ending `else`.

Comment: then I understand, read my edit and say if I've understood it better now?

Comment: It's to "shortcut" some deeper tests I run in a routine. I'd like to extract only the general results, thus I discard all the `else if` by setting the very first `if` = True so that all other should not be evaluated.

Comment: first of all, stop clicking downvote just because someone doesn't know the answer, and second of all, set a value instead of 'True' and 'False'. If more than 1 is true, it will print all the 'True'

Comment: Downvoting is a perfectly reasonable response to someone not knowing the answer, actually.

Comment: @ragefocker can you show an example of more than one `elif` printing?

Comment: I never downvoted anyone. It's not like a game or whatever and when I see some kind people taking time to answer a question, even an ultra basic one, I absolutely don't see why I should downvote. Anyway.

Answer (score -3):

In an [if, elif, else] blocks only the first block with the condition that  checks out will be executed.
but considering your situation I guess it needs more context to understand it fully, post part of the code you're testing or something with the same logic.